# Web Capacity Analysis Tool (WCAT) Tutorial

Tags: load-testing, wcat

I'm finding it very difficult to find any decent tutorials on how to get up and running with WCAT quickly.  Does anyone have a link to a decent tutorial on it that they found useful when trying to get to grips with WCAT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me the best thing that I used to get going with WCAT was to get their "sample" running, which tied to a base IIS installation with a single file.

Once I got that done, i found that the help documentation was very easy to understand, it is just the initial setup that was tricky.

Otherwise, this blog [posting](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/04/17/using-wcat-and-perfmon-to-performance-test-your-aspnet-application/) is pretty straightforward as well.

Comment: The release of Wcat 6.3 dates that blog post but I have got myself up and running in the using the samples.  Once I figured out that I had to uncomment some lines to get it to work at all it got easier.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, that initial learning curve is a bit steep, but it is a good product.

Comment: Would be nice if it had a Gui like the old "Web Application Stress Tool" (which doesn't work for me under windows 7 anyhow)

Comment: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/04/17/using-wcat-and-perfmon-to-performance-test-your-aspnet-application/ - complete URL to the blog post

Answer (score 2):

Just another option that helped me getting into this:

Using the **[WCAT Fiddler Extension](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/11/using-the-wcat-fiddler-extension-for-web-server-performance-tests.aspx)**.

This extension automatically generates all the necessary files and also calls them for you.

If you want to understand what's going behind the scenes, a good starting point for me was to use Process Explorer to see which files the Fiddler extension generates and how it calls them.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the WCAT Fiddler Extension was not working on my side and does not support POST so I decided to create my own. I shared the source code on github just incase your interested.

Here's the link: https://github.com/francischie/FiddlerWCAT

Answer (score 0):

I've also found [this article](http://theether.net/kb/100128) which combines [LogParser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24659) with [WCAT](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6). You may find that interesting too.